# Drawing colored balls from a bag

Tags: probability, random-variables, conditional-probability

Adam has a bag with $5$ balls that are either black or white.

(i) Suppose that the bag consists of $2$ black balls and $3$ white balls. Adam draws balls from the bag **with** replacement until he has drawn **at least** one ball of each color. Let $X$ be the number of draws. Find the probability mass function (pmf) of $X$.

(ii) Suppose that the number of black balls is a random variable $Y$ which can take values $2, 3$ or $4$ with equal probability. If Adam draws $5$ balls **with** replacement and finds that $3$ of the draws are black and $2$ are white, what is the conditional probability that $Y = 4$?

I am practicing for an exam and found this question. I have tried solving it but I have been unsuccessful and no solutions are available. Any assistance is much appreciated.

Comment: How far can you get with it?

Comment: @saulspatz Not far if at all. I tried applying ideas that I know such as checking whether $X$ satisfies a certain distribution, which seems like geometric but I am not sure. As for (ii) I have no idea whatsoever.

Comment: That's not the way to approach it.  There are only $2$ colors of balls.  Under what conditions is a ball of the second color first drawn on draw $n$?

Comment: If it's the second draw and the first draw was the first color, OR, if it's the first draw?

Comment: What's the probability that it's the fifth draw?

Comment: @saulspatz There can be at most only $4$ draws right? Since he stops when at least one of the two colors pops up. Either (B, W), (B, B, W), (W, B), (W, W, B), (W, W, W, B). Right?

Comment: @saulspatz Just realized it is with replacement so ignore that last comment. Ah! I can't figure this out.

Answer (score 0):

The basic idea of probability is counting.  You need to list out the ways something can happen, at least for the first few steps, and then look for the pattern.

For the first question, imagine that you draw the first ball.  There are two possibilities, black or white.  Suppose it is black.  Working from there, what is the distribution?  Then, suppose it is white, and do it again. You already stated that you guessed it was geometric; that is correct.  Work out the first few cases.  Given that the first draw is black, what is the probability that $X = 2$?  That $X = 3$? and so on.

The first branch, black is drawn first, has probability $\frac{2}{5}$.  Given that, $P(X=2) = P($white$) = \frac{3}{5}.$

Given black first, $P(X=3) = P($second was black and third was white$)$. That is $\frac{2}{5} \cdot \frac{3}{5}$. How exactly this spells out as geometric depends on how your class or textbook defines the geometric. For our purposes, $P(X=n$ and first draw was black$) = \frac{2}{5} \cdot \big({\frac{2}{5}}\big)^{n-2} \cdot \frac{3}{5}$

Likewise if the first draw is white, $P(X=n $and first draw was white$) = \frac{3}{5} \cdot {\frac{3}{5}}^{n-2} \cdot \frac{2}{5}$

And $P(X=n) = P(X=n$ and first was black$) + P(X=n$ and first was white).

For the second question, I think we need to assume that the number of black balls is chosen randomly once and then stays fixed.
The goal is $P(Y=4| 3$black, $2$ white).  A conditional probability follows Bayes' rule:
$$P(A|B) = P(B|A)\cdot \frac{P(A)}{P(B)}$$
Since there are only five draws you can map out the probabilities and total up each of them for the formula.  Let $A$ be "$Y=4$" and let $B$ be "$3$ black, $2$ white".

Comment: For (i) I sort of tried that. But I wasn't able to figure it out. For (ii) I'm not sure; that is how the question was put down...

Comment: Edited to add detail.

Comment: Your points make sense but I still can't figure it out. I've spent hours on this problem. Could you please give a solution?

Comment: How was the definition of geometric given to you?  If $X$ is geometric, is it the number of tries before the success, or the number of tries including the success?  It matters for how I write the answer.

Comment: I wasn't given an explicit definition of geometric...

Comment: Okay, then you can write it how you want.  I'll add more.

Comment: Just took a look at the book, it says that geometric is used "until your first success occurs". If you'd still like to make sure, the book is "Probability and Statistical Inference" by Hogg, Tanis and Zimmerman (10th edition)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/121021/discussion-between-robertthetutor-and-turnipsavocados).